# I'm unable to ssh into DigitalOcean Ubuntu(20.04) server? My sshd_config and authorised_keys files seems to be ok. Details below

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssh, terminal, digital-ocean

```
OpenSSH_8.6p1, OpenSSL 1.1.1k  25 Mar 2021
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: Connecting to 134.209.151.146 [134.209.151.146] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/clive/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/clive/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/clive/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/clive/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/clive/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/clive/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/clive/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk type -1
debug1: identity file /home/clive/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/clive/.ssh/id_ed25519 type 3
debug1: identity file /home/clive/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/clive/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk type -1
debug1: identity file /home/clive/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/clive/.ssh/id_xmss type -1
debug1: identity file /home/clive/.ssh/id_xmss-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_8.6
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_8.2p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.2
debug1: compat_banner: match: OpenSSH_8.2p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.2 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
debug1: Authenticating to 134.209.151.146:22 as 'clive'
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /home/clive/.ssh/known_hosts2: No such file or directory
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts: No such file or directory
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts2: No such file or directory
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ssh-ed25519
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY received
debug1: Server host key: ssh-ed25519 SHA256:X9T8dMRejOJgTDfHZo5kRvoVTD1moCRzX0F2jJmgGRk
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /home/clive/.ssh/known_hosts2: No such file or directory
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts: No such file or directory
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts2: No such file or directory
debug1: Host '134.209.151.146' is known and matches the ED25519 host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/clive/.ssh/known_hosts:2
debug1: rekey out after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: rekey in after 134217728 blocks
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/clive/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/clive/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/clive/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/clive/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/clive/.ssh/id_ed25519 ED25519 SHA256:808r4DrP8TnWnnXssQLn1rV0/fgWlyq3eF2s4Po2KZw
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/clive/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/clive/.ssh/id_xmss
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<ssh-ed25519,sk-ssh-ed25519@openssh.com,ssh-rsa,rsa-sha2-256,rsa-sha2-512,ssh-dss,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256@openssh.com>
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /home/clive/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Trying private key: /home/clive/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Trying private key: /home/clive/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Trying private key: /home/clive/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk
debug1: Offering public key: /home/clive/.ssh/id_ed25519 ED25519 SHA256:808r4DrP8TnWnnXssQLn1rV0/fgWlyq3eF2s4Po2KZw
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /home/clive/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk
debug1: Trying private key: /home/clive/.ssh/id_xmss
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
clive@134.209.151.146: Permission denied (publickey).
```

Can anyone help me figure it out? I'm trying to disable password and reconnect after updating authorized_keys file, but this is the error I get whenever I set PasswordAuthintication flag to no. I have already tried doing `ssh-copy-id -i ~/.ssh/test2.pub username@hostip` where test2 is the newly generated pub id. I'm kindof lost as where to begin. It seems my local machine is not able to find a folder called known_hosts2 but idk how to proceed further.

Answer (score 0):

- Are you connecting with a propery key (e.g. `sh-copy-id -i ~/.ssh/test2 username@hostip`)
- If your key in `/home/clive/.ssh/authorized-keys`?
- Is the file sufficiently well-protected?

E.g.:

```sh
chmod 700 .ssh
chmod 600 .ssh/authorized_keys
```

Also check your server-side debug log (usually in `/var/log`) for hints on what's causing failures in login.